# A rinnegan's vision

Tags: biology, vision

The Rinnegan has an array of powerful abilities.
But im more interested on it's actual visual capabilities.
The rinnegan has multiple irises outside of its first one,
And multiple limbal rings separating these irises.
Has no white cornea due to the irises covering half of the eyeball

My question is, with the eyeball having these properties
How would one with a rinnegan see any differently from a normal human eye?

[image: rinnegan]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It's unclear from your description how the "multiple irises" work. On vertebrates we have one iris that controls how much lit is permitted through the pupil. On your critter you haven't described what the redundant irises do. Without knowing that we're incapable of answering this question in any meaningful way.

Comment: @Kringle_Kryptid You're arguing with a bot. Even though it is a bot we still expect a basic level of decency in your conduct. Read my post  for why I think your post needs additional details and clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a doctor but pretty sure, in itself, it changes nothing. However, when combining it with the pupil, it basically allows you to be a little bit more cat-like. But really not much. Rinne-guy is basically a super lame cat

The role of the iris is to stretch out the pupil to let light in. The white of the eye is essentially useless. So right off the bat, the only thing you can hope to affect is how wide you can get your pupil (i.e. how much light you're letting in). There are two effects you describe: the iris is subdivided into several concentric rings, and the overall surface of the iris is larger. Let's discuss both.

**1. Subdivisions of the iris**

Utterly useless, as far as I can tell. All it allows you to do is to finely control the amount of stress you want to put on different sections of the iris. Which doesn't serve any purpose. The iris itself doesn't let light through. To see, what you want to stretch open is the pupil, and subdivisions do net help you do that better. A muscle works by contracting its length, up to a certain fraction of its original resting length (~70%). It makes no difference to the total stretching potential whether you have a 1cm-long muscle contracted to 0.7cm, or a string of 10 1mm-long muscles all contracted to 0.7mm. Maybe it will allow you to transition a little bit more smoothly between a fully contracted and fully dilated pupil, but I fail to see which practical purpose that could serve.

**2. Larger surface of the iris**

Well, taking the discussion above, having a longer length for the muscles that stretch the pupil out does allow you to stretch it a little bit further. Having a wider maximal aperture for your eye theoretically lets you see a little bit better in the dark. The effect will be very minor tho. The maximal radius of the pupil amongst humans of the same age can easily vary by a factor 2. Even if you double the radius of your iris, that will lead to less than a doubling of the pupil radius. Less than the statistical deviation naturally observed among us. Think about it, cats need to make their pupil cover almost all of the eye surface when they want to see in the dark. You won't get that effect by simply making the iris longer (it can't contract enough).

**3. Ladies...**

As an aside,  [studies suggest](https://escholarship.org/content/qt0964610k/qt0964610k.pdf?t=nfa9wu) that both sexes "use the limbal ring as a probabilistic indicator of reproductive fitness". With so many rings, rinne-guy might get *a lot* of attention in the club

Comment: It is usually recommended to wait before accepting an answer. Especially since I'm definitely no expert in biology-related stuff, and relying on nothing more than common sense and google